# Narrowing types in typescript array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an array of type MyArray.

```js
type Maybe<T> = T | null;
type MyArray =  Maybe<Materials>[] | Maybe<Seasons>[] | Seasons[] | Materials[] | null | undefined;
type Value = Seasons | Materials;
```

Example code:

```js
   if (!myArray?.length) {
      return;
    }

    const isValid = myArray.includes(value); // typescript is complaining about value
```

The issue is when I highlight value:

```js
Argument of type Seasons | Materials is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: How do you declare myArray, and what is the type of value. Can you create a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This error is actually legit, there is a mismatch because:

- On one hand we have a `Seasons | Materials` (the value)
- On the other hand we have (the array):

  - Either a box of `Seasons[]` that won't accept the value because it *could be* a `Materials`
  - Or a box of `Materials[]` that won't accept the value either because it *could be* a `Seasons`

We can try to fix it by using an intermediate `includes` function, such as:

```js
type ElementOf<A extends any[], B> = B extends A[number] ? B : never

function includes<A extends any[], B>(list: A, element: ElementOf<A, B>): boolean {
    return list.includes(element)
}
```

This function ensures that:

- Semantically, we keep either a box of `Seasons[]`, or a box of `Materials[]`, but **not** a box of `(Seasons | Materials)[]`
- We have to use an array for the first argument
- We have to use a value whose type may be contained in the array from the first argument

```js
const isValid = includes(myArray, value)
```

You can check on [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhCGBnA9gO0VAvFA5PHUAPrgEY4CwAUKJFALLzAQBOAlvADYbY4DGBxHABMKlKjWgMQJCAB4AKgD4sUeUSioArhw7jwkkAEFmzeCBX0zM2QyZtOiRQG0AuuqnW4SNI9fqvKOh+xLYs7FzBGtoc6pqoQhAAZqyoEEJUerQAapya0NgBPu6MYQ4ZYhUSUACiHBAAthCowADyibKGUBAAHkzxGPCoIK4ANFAAQsrY4129TUIYhk5a9TLMbgD8E1AAXBoQAG4s5YlxvMCsaFApvByaCYgds30LUIPDLmOTABQcrIjAPaGMYQOqNZp7WoNJqtdrAiaKACUexIyGQdUGUAA3lQoHioMwIMBNMxUFA-gCAHQ3O4Pb6g6HNRFUAC+5Rp9wgiG+TgAjGMAExjADMn1wAAsICAcIioAB6OVQITILmoHDAKC8ZD1MCsOpjHCS6WawaoZAamRvRCIVgAc1SQigwGQUVWx0oHLpOESaJwBqNMvliuVqvVmu1uv1uB9yAI-w05reZPgJjMVE9XJ5Wh0BvwBrIbiQUAAcmhi9F4CQ6jYjKmQIoDSJZQrwzq9VyoDJePBNIhoMI4wMoDk7hB06hbpzuctorm-aQcIWMKXUOWdJXq3Ra6Z6waIIGWyHEGqNVq23VOxBu73+-vrhgzRr4MPcmOKqcJxcrjHvvVt2Y9i3YwdzGA5Xz2Ec8mRKADmQVhHRxSh8WuRIoG+ABCP9gLMDZKTqVBbWAcVZUQ5DkMJYlSVxfE2SQ-EtXQDV-hHeCVAzbksLrUDX2ZOi8QYlA6jw5BbW+ZjOHg3jaKAA).

---

*Previous answer:*

I'm pretty sure we can fix this issue by simplifying the definition of the `MyArray` type:

```js
type MyArray = Maybe<Array<Maybe<Materials> | Maybe<Seasons>>> | undefined
// or: type MyArray = Array<Maybe<Materials> | Maybe<Seasons>> | null | undefined
```

```js
function foo(myArray: MyArray, value: Value): void {
    // myArray: Maybe<Array<Value | null>> | undefined (or, equivalent -> myArray: Array<Value | null> | null | undefined)
    if (!myArray?.length) {
        return
    }
    // myArray: Array<Value | null>
    const isValid = myArray.includes(value)
    console.log(isValid)
}
```

Somehow, when the type of `myArray` is a union type of arrays:

```js
type MyArray =
  | Maybe<Materials>[]
  | Maybe<Seasons>[]
  | null
  | undefined
```

Instead of an array of a union type:

```js
type MyArray = Array<Maybe<Materials> | Maybe<Seasons>> | null | undefined
```

Then the [type inference when using the `includes` function](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/663b19fe4a7c4d4ddaa61aedadd28da06acd27b6/src/lib/es2016.array.include.d.ts#L7) is broken, so we end up with the type `never` instead of `Maybe<Value>` (or `Value | null`, same thing).

I don't know if this behavior is intended or a bug, it might be interesting to look for an open issue on the TypeScript repository mentioning this, or create a new one.

([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhCGBnA9gO0VAvFA5PHUAPrgEY4CwAUKJFALLzAQBOAlvADYbY4DGBxHABMKlKjWgMQJCAB4AKgD4sUeUSioArhw5UA9Hon0QAQWbN4IFfUszZDJm06JFAbQC66qXbhI0Lj3VfFHRA4gcWdi4wjW0OdU1UIQgAM1ZUCCFxcElTc0trbzkzCxB7WzkIpy5lcIrZYP9FZoSk1PTMqmzaADVOTWhsRvQvRkjnLrEplMTeYFY0KBTkZAAKAFs80oAuYxLLABooADd+iF2+jgGASl3j5FYhKABvKih3qCMTFQlkFKhNvsrB8QSCDDZpHJVgAiXjQ9TQoTw4jQ+DIqDQkjorQ6a4eWpQRLJNIZLKUEGsf6rACEgPyIAA-AA6DgQVAAc2AAAtri83qD3swIMBNMxUPz3gBfCWfHJQABCPxyfwBWwKArBeigMLhCKRCLRCKx6hxHDx7hlRgAwipVr9-nTSnitOsZMxPODYejEd7DSjjcRTTLeP5gFBWIhLo8VI7LEz0rwrslEKtTlcINdg-5kKyWch2asI1GhJnKNLKEA))

Comment: MyArray type is generated on the backend which I cant change to simplify it. Yes you right, second annotation works as a cast, ideally I wanted not to cast but I ended up doing: `myArray as
      (Seasons | Materials | Maybe<Seasons> | Maybe<Materials>)[]
      | null
      | undefined; `

Comment: I see, [type assertion](https://github.com/ruizb/glossary-typescript#type-assertion) it is then! BTW you can still simplify it a bit with `(Maybe<Seasons> | Maybe<Materials>)[]`, since the `Seasons | Materials` part is redundant: `A | B | Maybe<A> | Maybe<B>` is the same as `A | B | A | null | B | null`, which simplifies to `A | B | null`, or `Maybe<A> | Maybe<B>`.

Comment: Now that I think about it, a union of arrays and an array of union type is not the same: on one hand you have either a box full of apples or a box full of oranges, whereas on the other hand you have a box full of apples or oranges (not the same meaning). This is probably why you end up with this type error, because a value that's either `Seasons` or `Materials` cannot be in a box of `Seasons` only, or a box of `Materials` only.

Comment: I edited to provide a (I think) better answer to this issue.